# Filtering by multiple classes clicked Jquery

Tags: jquery, filter

I need to make a multiple filter that, by the `.tax` clicked, can hide or not the user's choice. I need to filter by element text.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tax.price').click(function() {
    let price = $(this).text();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.list > .item').each(function() {
      if (price == $(this).find('.price').text()) {
        $(this).removeClass('hide');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('hide');
      }
    });
  });

  $('.tax.category').click(function() {
    let category = $(this).text();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.list > .item').each(function() {
      if (category == $(this).find('.category').text()) {
        $(this).removeClass('hide');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('hide');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="tax price">Free</li>
  <li class="tax price">$100</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="tax category">Category 1</li>
  <li class="tax category">Category 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="list">
  <span class="item">
    <span class="category">Category 2</span>
  <span class="price">$100</span>
  </span>
  <span class="item">
    <span class="category">Category 1</span>
  <span class="price">$100</span>
  </span>
  <span class="item">
    <span class="category">Category 1</span>
  <span class="price">Free</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lucaskazama/9gsLzmc5/56/)

Comment: The code seems to be working as you describe. Can you give details of the issue you're having. Also note that you get better answers if you include all relevant code within the question, as it's easier and quicker for people to read and understand your code. I've edited it for you in this instance.

Comment: In my code it can select all categories, I want to limit it to only one at a time.
Example: 
Free and Category 1 ✅ (Like that)
Free and $100 ⛔ (Not that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `data-attribute` to your `.tax` element just to know whether its `price` or `category` .Then , use this `data-attr` to remove `active` class from other element and keep only to one `active` element .

Now, inside `each` loop you can have two condition either one option will be selected or both so depending on this change `&&` or `||` and show divs which statisfy that condition.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.price ,.category').click(function() {
    var data_name = $(this).data("name")
    $("." + data_name).not(this).removeClass('active'); //remove active from others..
    $(".item").addClass('hide'); //hide your item
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    
    //get text value of active class..
    var price = $(".price.active").text().trim();
    var category = $(".category.active").text().trim();
    
    $('.list > .item').each(function() {
      var inside_price = $(this).find('.price').text()
      var inside_category = $(this).find('.category').text()
      //change logic to || and && depending active class
      var use_or_and = ($(".price.active").length && $(".category.active").length) ? (price == inside_price && category == inside_category) : (price == inside_price || category == inside_category)
      if (use_or_and) {
        $(this).removeClass('hide');
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--added data-attr-->
<ul>
  <li class="tax price" data-name="price">Free</li>
  <li class="tax price" data-name="price">$100</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="tax category" data-name="category">Category 1</li>
  <li class="tax category" data-name="category">Category 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="list">
  <span class="item">
    <span class="category">Category 2</span>
  <span class="price">$100</span>
  </span>
  <span class="item">
    <span class="category">Category 1</span>
  <span class="price">$100</span>
  </span>
  <span class="item">
    <span class="category">Category 1</span>
  <span class="price">Free</span>
  </span>
</div>
```